# sqlalchemy: postgresql-level function

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, properties, plpgsql

I have a problem with my sqlalchemy model, that has properties for previous and next date of some event. These properties are kinda complex for `sqlalchemy.orm.hybrid_property` decoration, and I have an idea of creating function with `PL/pgSQL`, that will do the same thing. My question is the following: "Is it possible to do it?" and "How can I do it?" (I tried to read official docs, but I didn't find, what I need).

model:

```py
class SomeModel(Base):
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    last_reminded_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    repeat_end_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    category = Column(Enum(ReminderCategoryEnum), nullable=False)
    repeat_type = Column(
        Enum(ReminderRepeatTypeEnum),
        default=ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER,
        server_default=ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER.name,
        nullable=False,
    )
    repeat_interval = Column(RelativeInterval(native=True), nullable=False)
    is_finished = Column(Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)
    is_notified = Column(Boolean, default=False, server_default=false(), nullable=False)

    @property
    def previous_date(self) -> Optional[datetime.datetime]:
        now = get_utc_now()
        date = self.date.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        if self.date.replace(tzinfo=UTC) < now:
            if self.repeat_type == ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER:
                return date
            if self.last_reminded_at:
                last_reminded_at = self.last_reminded_at.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
            else:
                last_reminded_at = None
            if not last_reminded_at or last_reminded_at + self.repeat_interval < now:
                previous_date = date
                while previous_date + self.repeat_interval < now:
                    previous_date += self.repeat_interval
                return previous_date
            else:
                return self.last_reminded_at
        return None

    @property
    def next_date(self) -> Optional[datetime.datetime]:
        now = get_utc_now()  # datetime.datetime.now with UTC tz
        date = self.date.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        if date > now:
            return date
        if self.repeat_type == ReminderRepeatTypeEnum.NEVER:
            return None
        next_date = self.previous_date + self.repeat_interval
        if (
            self.repeat_end_date
            and next_date < self.repeat_end_date.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        ):
            return next_date
        if not self.repeat_end_date:
            return next_date
        return None
```

So, `previous_date` has while loop and `next_date` depends on `previous_date` property, so I guess, `hybrid_property` will not work, that is why I have a problem with it (Or, probably, even on sqlalchemy-level I can do it with while loop?).

upd: RelativeInterval - is PostgreSQL interval, that convert value to dateutil relativedelta object and back (to relativedelta is psycopg2-level converting).

Comment: Add updates to question text not in comments.